# Resume Uget download started in windows in ubuntu

Tags: download-manager, uget

I have installed Uget both on Win 8 and Ubuntu. I started a download with win8 and paused it halfway.  Is there a way to resume the same download in Ubuntu? I have access to the physical file in my windows download folder. These are the files: 
ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso 
ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.aria2

Answer (score 2):

Michael Tunnell from uGet:

This is an interesting question, I've never considered this option...it might be possible right now but it heavily depends on the kind of download...if downloading from a site like Mediafire then I highly doubt it because those sites use Session Cookies and you could possibly move the files over, the session cookie and add it to the queue via import but I highly doubt it would be successful because of the cookie issue.

If the download is a direct link to a file then it is possible as the session cookie wouldn't be needed.

To be honest, I am not sure - I will have to do some testing to see if this is possible.

Comment: He wants to download an Ubuntu ISO, that's a direct link for sure :)

Comment: yes but that is a single example...and not explaining that it wouldn't work everywhere would be careless on my part.